# How do I run a command in a different tty?

Tags: shell-script, io

Suppose there are two terminals, `pts/0` and `pts/1`.

In `pts/0`, I have fired a command:

```
ls>/dev/pts/1
```

Then, we only get the output of the `ls` command in `pts/1`, but I want to run a command as well as its output both on `pts/1`.

I tried `"echo ls">/dev/pts/1`, but instead the output of the `ls` command, "ls", is printed on `pts/1`.

How can I do it?

[image: What I tried]

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10376251/2072269

Comment: Did you try `ls>/dev/pts/1 </dev/pts/1 2>/dev/pts/1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy and paste [this code](http://www.humbug.in/2010/utility-to-send-commands-or-data-to-other-terminals-ttypts/) on `ttyecho.c`

Compile it using `gcc -O3 -o ttyecho ttyecho.c`

Use it `./ttyecho -n /dev/pts/1 ls`

Comment: @Tiger Be aware that the command string will first be parsed in the current terminal's shell but executed in the environment of the target's.  You can see the difference with `ttyecho -n /dev/pts1 ls $$` and `ttyecho -n /dev/pts1 ls '$$'`

Comment: There is also a repository with this tool. I have added a procedure how to check the correct escapement of the string to be sent to the other terminal: https://github.com/osospeed/ttyecho/issues/1

Answer (score 3):

Depends on your terminal environment:

- In Linux with the console: `openvt _command_`
- Within a terminal in screen: `screen _command_`
- Within X Windows (Mac as well): `xterm -e "_command_"`

Comment: For people reading this question, this is the right answer.  Specifically, `openvt` is the correct way to do this on most Linux distributions

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me why you want to do this; depending on the exact reason, the *clusterssh* package may do what you want.

The idea of clusterssh is that you start several `ssh` commands to several machines (or possibly the same machine multiple times). You then get a terminal window for each ssh session, plus one entry window of clusterssh. If you type something into one of the terminal windows, it gets sent only to that ssh session; if you type it into the main entry window, however, it gets sent to *all* sessions.

If that's not what you need, it might be useful if you could explain *why* you want to do this.

Comment: Yeah, clusterssh is a nice tool for working with a small set of hosts in parallel.