# How to 'hash -r' and refresh all shells?

Tags: bash, command-line

This is related to [What is the purpose of the hash command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86012/56041) After installing a program I am looking for a way to tell all open shells to update their cache. I often have 6 to 8 of them open and I don't want to have to run `hash -r` 8 or 10 times. Anything more than once is a waste of time and effort.

After installing a program in one shell, is it possible to either (1) have all shells rebuild their view of cached programs; or (2) rebuild the table and use that table for all other shells? If it is possible, then how do we do it?

---

Here is the relevant section of `man 1 hash`, but it does not discuss how to achieve results globally.

```
   hash [-lr] [-p filename] [-dt] [name]
          Each time hash is invoked, the full pathname of the command name
          is  determined  by searching the directories in $PATH and remem‐
          bered.  Any previously-remembered pathname is discarded.  If the
          -p option is supplied, no path search is performed, and filename
          is used as the full filename of  the  command.   The  -r  option
          causes  the  shell  to  forget all remembered locations.  The -d
          option causes the shell to forget  the  remembered  location  of
          each  name.   If the -t option is supplied, the full pathname to
          which each name corresponds is printed.  If multiple name  argu‐
          ments  are  supplied  with  -t,  the  name is printed before the
          hashed full pathname.  The -l option causes output  to  be  dis‐
          played in a format that may be reused as input.  If no arguments
          are given, or if only -l is supplied, information  about  remem‐
          bered  commands  is printed.  The return status is true unless a
          name is not found or an invalid option is supplied.
```

Comment: If you installed a program in one of the $PATH directories, you shouldn't even need to rehash. Curious why you're using -r, as well.

Comment: @Jeff - You certainly need it even when installing on `$PATH`; see, for example, [Path not being honored?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/226149/83961) on OS X stack exchange. As for `-r`, I staterted using it to try and get Bash to forget the old version of the program installed in `/usr/bin` (re: OS X question). If you have another recommendation, then I'd be happy to use it.

Comment: You're replacing an existing $PATH'd binary with a different one of the same name?

Comment: @jeff - Yes. For example, I might be upgrading (displacing?) `emacs` or `openssl` located in `/usr/bin` with a new one located in `/usr/local/bin`. I never overwrite or delete what's in `/usr/bin`. I install something new in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Won't the relative sequence in $PATH influence which one runs? Or are you also deleting the /usr/bin copy?

Comment: @Jeff presumably `/usr/local/bin` comes first in the `PATH`...

Comment: @jww, could you spell out the steps to reproduce this issue, in this question, please?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I added a pseudo-script at the bottom of my solution which I think produces something like what jww is experiencing.

Comment: It does sound like you'll need a `hash -d that-program` in each of the shells; seems a rather niche problem to have: several long-running shells open, with stale hash table entries for a program that you've replaced that occurs twice in the shell's $PATH.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I completely agree. I wouldn't consider this to be a problem or even much of an inconvenience and I'm skeptical that there is a solution of the form requested which doesn't introduce more potential complexity than it's worth. That said, we should try to answer questions as asked, right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the TLDR solution: if you want to programmatically execute commands in pre-existing shell sessions then you can use the `ttyecho` program.

**WARNING:** *Note that this is not in general a safe operation and is sensitive to the state of each session. As user StephenKitt points out, this approach requires that each terminal session have a prompt that is waiting to receive input.*

An alternative solution would be to effectively disable path-hashing by adding the `PROMPT_COMMAND='hash -r'` statement to your `~/.bashrc` file. This won't affect currently running sessions, but will prevent this issue from arising in the future.

Finally, you could consider using a terminal multiplexer such as [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki), which supports executing commands in multiple terminals simultaneously.

A more detailed response follows.

---

It seems to me that the basic functionality that you're looking for is the ability to programmatically execute commands in other active shell sessions. I found that this question (of how to execute commands in other shell sessions) has been addressed elsewhere on this site, e.g.:

- [How do I run a command in a different tty?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260503/how-do-i-run-a-command-in-a-different-tty)
- [Execute command in remote active terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39145/execute-command-in-remote-active-terminal)

It seems that the easiest way to execute commands in other active shell sessions is to use the `ttyecho` utility. The `ttyecho` program is a small, self-contained, single-file C program. Here are a couple of references to the `ttyecho` source-code and documentation:

- http://www.humbug.in/2010/utility-to-send-commands-or-data-to-other-terminals-ttypts/
- https://github.com/osospeed/ttyecho

For completeness, here is the source code:

```c
// ttyecho.c
// Original author: Pratik Sinha
// http://www.humbug.in/2010/utility-to-send-commands-or-data-to-other-terminals-ttypts/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void print_help(char *prog_name) {
    printf("Usage: %s [-n] DEVNAME COMMAND\n", prog_name);
    printf("Usage: '-n' is an optional argument if you want to push a new line at the end of the text\n");
    printf("Usage: Will require 'sudo' to run if the executable is not setuid root\n");
    exit(1);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *cmd, *nl = "\n";
    int i, fd;
    int devno, commandno, newline;
    int mem_len;
    devno = 1; commandno = 2; newline = 0;
    if (argc < 3) {
        print_help(argv[0]);
    }
    if (argc > 3 && argv[1][0] == '-' && argv[1][1] == 'n') {
        devno = 2; commandno = 3; newline=1;
    } else if (argc > 3 && argv[1][0] == '-' && argv[1][1] != 'n') {
        printf("Invalid Option\n");
        print_help(argv[0]);
    }
    fd = open(argv[devno],O_RDWR);
    if(fd == -1) {
        perror("open DEVICE");
        exit(1);
    }
    mem_len = 0;
    for ( i = commandno; i < argc; i++ ) {
        mem_len += strlen(argv[i]) + 2;
        if ( i > commandno ) {
            cmd = (char *)realloc((void *)cmd, mem_len);
        } else { //i == commandno
            cmd = (char *)malloc(mem_len);
        }

        strcat(cmd, argv[i]);
        // strcat(cmd, " ");
    }
  if (newline == 0)
        usleep(225000);
    for (i = 0; cmd[i]; i++)
        ioctl (fd, TIOCSTI, cmd+i);
    if (newline == 1)
        ioctl (fd, TIOCSTI, nl);
    close(fd);
    free((void *)cmd);
    exit (0);
}
```

If you download the source code or copy-paste it to a file named `ttyecho.c`, then you should be able to compile the program like so:

```bsh
gcc ttyecho.c -o ttyecho
```

Once the program is compiled you should be able to use it to run any command you'd like in anther shell session. This included being able to programmatically run the `hash -r` command in every active shell session. Here is one way to clear the hashed commands on all of the shell sessions on Mac OS X:

```bsh
for _tty in /dev/ttys*; do ./ttyecho -n 'hash -r' ${_tty}; done
```

On a Linux machine you would do something like this instead:

```bsh
for _tty in /dev/pts/*; do ./ttyecho -n 'hash -r' ${_tty}; done
```

Since some comments asked for a way to reproduce the issue, I've included the following script to illustrate how hashing can affect which program is executed.

```bsh
# Create two bin directories
mkdir -p ~/local/bin1
mkdir -p ~/local/bin2

# Add the directories to the PATH, with bin2 preceding bin1
export PATH="${HOME}/local/bin2:${HOME}/local/bin1:${PATH}"

# Create a test script and put it in the bin1 directory
cat <<HEREDOC > ~/local/bin1/test.sh
#!/bin/bash
# test.sh

echo "This is test #1, it's in ~/local/bin1"
HEREDOC

# Make the script executable
chmod +x ~/local/bin1/test.sh

# Verify that the script is found by using the "which" command
which test.sh

# Output:
#
#   /home/username/local/bin1/test.sh

# Verify that the script is found by using the "type" command
type test.sh

# Output:
#
#   test.sh is /home/username/local/bin1/test.sh

# Test the script
test.sh

# Output:
#
#   This is test #1, it's in ~/local/bin1

# Now hash the test script
hash test.sh

# Verify that the script has been hashed by using the "type" command
type test.sh

# Output:
#
#   test.sh is hashed (/home/username/local/bin1/test.sh)

# Now create a second test script and put it in bin2 to shadow the first
cat <<HEREDOC > ~/local/bin2/test.sh
#!/bin/bash
# test.sh

echo "This is test #2, it's in ~/local/bin2"
HEREDOC

# Make the second test script executable
chmod +x ~/local/bin2/test.sh

# Verify that the bin2 test script take priority over the bin1 test script
which -a test.sh

# Output:
#
#   /home/username/local/bin2/test.sh
#   /home/username/local/bin1/test.sh

which test.sh

# Output:
#
#   /home/username/local/bin2/test.sh

# Try to run the test script
test.sh

# Ouput:
#
#   This is test #1, it's in ~/local/bin1

# NOTE: Even though bin2/test.sh comes before bin1/test.sh in the PATH,
#       it's bin1/test.sh that is executed. What's going on?

# Use the "type" command to see which script is being executed
type test.sh

# Output
#
#   test.sh is hashed (/home/username/local/bin1/test.sh)

# NOTE: That explains the seeming contradiction.

# Clear the hashed command
hash -d test.sh

# Check that the hashed command has been cleared
type test.sh

# Output:
#
#   test.sh is /home/username/local/bin2/test.sh

# Run the test.sh command
test.sh

# Output:
#
#   This is test #2, it's in ~/local/bin2
```

I also found an alternative approach described elsewhere on this site:

- [Disable bash's cache of executables in the path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150922/disable-bashs-cache-of-executables-in-the-path)

The solution there was to use the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable to continuously clear the path cache, e.g. by adding the following line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
PROMPT_COMMAND='hash -r'
```

Note that this will only affect new sessions and not your pre-existing sessions unless you also execute that command in those sessions.

Finally, you may want to consider using a terminal multiplexer such as [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki). Here is a relevant post from this site:

- [Run command in multiple active shells simultaneously](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298702/run-command-in-multiple-active-shells-simultaneously)

Comment: How do you know `ttyecho` is writing to a prompt that’s waiting for a command? Say you have an IRC client in one terminal, an editor in another, and a shell with a complex command you’re working on (that’s supposed to delete a bunch of files, for added fun)...

Comment: @StephenKitt Is this a rhetorical question? If so, I should say that I don't think that this is a good idea. But it sounds like what the question was asking for, no? Personally I don't consider having to run `hash -d` a few times to be much of an inconvenience.

Comment: @StephenKitt I added an alternative solution (or approximate solution) that doesn't involve injecting commands into active sessions.

Comment: No, it’s not a rhetorical question. It’s an interesting approach, but it does have significant drawbacks, especially for someone like the OP with a bunch of long-lived shells lying around. You end up sending text strings to all terminals, not just “programmatically execut[ing] commands in other active shell sessions”. I would recommend adding the fact that you don’t think this is a good idea to the answer itself...

Comment: @StephenKitt I completely agree. I've added a cautionary note, per your suggestion.